# How to dynamic change position and record that position javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a project to build which contains 14 columns across the page, those columns will have dropbox where user are allow to drag and drop pdf files, once use drag and drop a pdf file to the first column a line across all columns will appear to indicate that the user can proceed droping the same file forward in the same line. if another new pdf file is dragged it will go under the previous one. This means that there will be a lot of files throughout all columns, column 1 might have 3 files columns 7 might have 10. At the moment I'm doing the dropboxes using div but i dont think that is very dynamic because I could have between 1 to 10,000 files, does that means I would have to create 10,000 div with different position? I believe there must be a better way to do this as I need this to be more dynamic. And if it becomes dynamic data, how would I save the data information (position of file location) so next time I visit the page the information will be allocated in the same position? (I believe that would require php but i didnt get to that part yet).

This code does not contain all divs, it contains 4 columns each columns has 1 dropbox inside at the moment, but that number will be much higher which is why I think this dropbox should be dynamic. I have not include the css neither the javascript files. As I figured its irrelevant. if any of you want to see it I will post it.

HTML

```
<div class="columnContent">
            <p>Customer's order</p>
            <div class="dropBox" ondrop="drag_drop(event)"
             ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragstart=
            "dragInfo(event)" id="dp1" draggable="true">
                <p id="para1">Drag file here</p>
                <div class="leftAlign">
                <img src="pdf.jpg" id="pdfImg" style="visibility: hidden">
                <p1 id="pdfInfo"></p1><br>
                </div>
                <input id="txt1" placeholder="Customer's code" style="visibility: 
                 hidden"><br>
                <input id="txt2" placeholder="Customer's size" style="visibility:
                hidden"><br>
               <input id="txt3" placeholder="Customer's DD" style="visibility:
                hidden"><br>
                <button id="btn" style="visibility: hidden">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columnContent">
            <p>Planned</p>
            <div class="dropBox" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)" > 
         ####(I think these boxes should be dynamic or I 
          will have to create 100s of them)#####
               <p ondragstart="dragInfo(event)" draggable="true">Drag file here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columnContent" >
            <p>Checked</p>
            <div class="dropBox" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
            style="visibility: hidden"> ###(I think these 
         boxes should be dynamic or I will have to create 100s of them)###
                <p ondragstart="dragInfo(event)" draggable="true">Drag file here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columnContent">
            <p>Coil @ I.S</p>
            <div class="dropBox" ondrop="drop(event)" 
ondragover="allowDrop(event)" 
       style="visibility: hidden"> ####(I think these boxes should 
       be dynamic or I will have to create 100s of them)####
                <p ondragstart="dragInfo(event)" draggable="true">Drag file 
here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after Jquery UI. This will simplify the whole process much better and can be seen at http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ or http://jqueryui.com/sortable/. I didn't use to like jquery but make the move and I don't think you'll ever regret it (if you don't use it already).

Comment: Nope thats not what Im after but thanks anyway. I got everything to drag/drop thats not the issue, the issue is as explained above. Thanks anyway.